# NX use import on Libs that is inside an App to use apps scss files

Tags: angular, sass, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I'm working with NX and Angular project and I'm trying to share styles with them. Consider the following structure:

```
├── apps
│   ├── client-a
│   │   ├── src
│   │   │   ├── **/*
│   │   │   ├── style
│   │   │   │   ├── import.scss
│   │   │   │   ├── color.scss
│   │   │   │   ├── typo.scss
│   ├── client-b
│   │   ├── src
│   │   │   ├── **/*
│   │   │   ├── style
│   │   │   │   ├── import.scss
│   │   │   │   ├── color.scss
│   │   │   │   ├── typo.scss
├── libs
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── **/**
│   ├── store
│   │   ├── **/**
│   ├── product
│   │   ├── **/**
```

For each of the `libs` module I have their own style to create the visuals. But the really important thing is, I want to use the variables defined on the `apps`. So when I build the app `client-a` I know it will follow the colors, typography, spaces, etc.. That are defined on the styles for `client-a`. Same for `client-b`.

This way I can style the `libs` to have a default look, but follow some variables for each app.

What I did to solve this issue on development environment was to set this config on file `project.json` on each `app`.

```
{
  "name": "client-a",
  [...]
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        [...]
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            ".",
            "apps/client-a/src"
          ]
        }
      },
    }
  }
}
```

The compile works when I run

> npx nx run clienta:serve --configuration=development

But doesn't work when I run

> npx nx run clienta:build --configuration=production

Is there a way to fix this? So on Libs Modules I can just import the files like this: `@import 'style/import.scss';` which is a reference for `./apps/{client}/scr/style`.